# Why the x is 5050?

Tags: java

```
for(i = 1;i <= 100;i++)
    for(j = i; j <= 100; j++)
        x++;
System.out.println(x);
```

First I thought that the result would be 10.000, but it was 5050. Why? What does the *i* changes?

Comment: I assume `x` is an integer initialized to 0?  You should include all details relevant to the question in your post.

Answer (score 8):

The answer 5050 is correct, given the assumption that `x` is 0 (as it appears based on your results).  The reason it is not 10,000 is the line `j = i` instead of e.g. `j = 1`, which makes it 100 + 99 + 98 + ... + 1 = 5050.

Comment: This assumes `x` was initialized to 0.  The OP hasn't even stated that.  Not saying this is a bad answer, but I think it's worth mentioning as a precondition.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong would have to assume 0 at the time of execution of the code and the output OP got was 5050, x = 0 is the only number that would make that true for the given code

Comment: Sure, that's a fair point.  If it was me I would still put something at the beginning like "Assuming `x` is initialized to 0, the answer 5050 is correct" just to be as clear as possible.  Just a suggestion, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

At first `i` is `1`, so `j` goes from 1 too 100 and the inner loop does 100 iterations, which means `x` is incremented 100 times.

The next time, `i` becomes `2`, so `j` goes from 2 to 100. That means 99 iterations and `x` is incremented 99 times and so on and so forth...

That's the sum of all numbers from 100 to 1, which is `(100 * (100 + 1)) / 2 == 5050`

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop executes `(100 - i) times` on each iteration of the outer loop. i.e. when the value of `i = 0` in the outer loop, the inner loop executes `100 times`, when the value of `i = 1` in the outer loop, the inner loop executes `99 times` and so on and so forth. When adding all these values `100 + 99 + 98 + ... + 1 = 5050`